# Center UISegmentedControl within a UISearchBar

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, uikit

I am using the built-in search scope with a `UISearchDisplayController`, and I only have 2 segments.

The problem is that our design needs the buttons to be smaller and centered (it especially looks bad on iPad because the buttons are stretched really wide).

Is there a way to center the `UISegmentedControl` and make it smaller? I already have the `UISegmentedControl` pulled out by looping over `subViews`. And I can set the width of each segment with `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex`, but the control is docked to the left. How can I center it?

PS - my app is MonoTouch (Xamarin.iOS), but Obj-C answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding this via IB or programmatically? In IB, I had to turn off "Autoresize Subviews" and do the resizing of the control dynamically via code. I put the controls I needed to resize into a view that I could bind to then center my control within that view. Here's a sample. I had 2 buttons that I put side-by-side in landscape mode, but it should give you an idea.

```
// get the current sizes of the things we are moving
CGRect saveRect = self.viewButtons.frame;  // the enclosing view
CGRect addLocRect = self.buttonAddLocation.frame;  // button 1
CGRect connectRect = self.buttonConnect.frame;     // button 2

// This will be set below in one of the if-else branches
CGFloat buttonWidth = 0;

// determine the offset from the left/right based on device and orientation
int offsetLeft = 0;
int offsetRight = 0;
if ([self isIphone]) {
    offsetLeft = (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) ? OFFSET_LEFT_PORTRAIT_IPHONE : OFFSET_LEFT_LANDSCAPE_IPHONE;
    offsetRight = (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) ? OFFSET_RIGHT_PORTRAIT_IPHONE : OFFSET_RIGHT_LANDSCAPE_IPHONE;

} else {
    offsetLeft = (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) ? OFFSET_LEFT_PORTRAIT_IPAD : OFFSET_LEFT_LANDSCAPE_IPAD;
    offsetRight = offsetLeft;
}


// change the size & location of the buttons to maximize the area for the location list
// no matter what orientation, the button frame will fill the bottom of the screen
saveRect.size.width = _windowWidth -offsetLeft - offsetRight;

// for Landscape, move the buttons to side-by-side at the bottom of the window
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {

    // size & move the buttons to fit side-by-side
    buttonWidth = (saveRect.size.width)*.4;

    // addLocRect.origin.x += offset;
    addLocRect.origin.y = saveRect.size.height - addLocRect.size.height ;

    connectRect.origin.x = saveRect.size.width - buttonWidth - offsetRight;
    connectRect.origin.y = saveRect.size.height - connectRect.size.height;

} else { // Portrait

    // move the buttons down to the bottom of the frame, stacked
    // size the buttons to be fully across the screen
    buttonWidth = saveRect.size.width-2*offsetLeft;

    addLocRect.origin.y = 0 ; // at the top of the button view
    addLocRect.origin.x = offsetLeft;
    connectRect.origin.y = saveRect.size.height - connectRect.size.height;
    connectRect.origin.x = offsetLeft;

}

connectRect.size.width = buttonWidth;
addLocRect.size.width = buttonWidth;
self.buttonAddLocation.frame = addLocRect;
self.buttonConnect.frame = connectRect;
```

Comment: I am adding a UISearchBar + Search Controller from XCode/IB. I tried setting AutoResizeSubviews to false on the storyboard, but no luck. Changing the UISegmentedControl's frame doesn't seem to do anything. Does your example use a UISearchBar with a search scope? I don't see anything about those controls.

Comment: No, my example does not use a UISearchBar, but you should be able to get the frame of the searchbar and use that to position your segmented control within the searchbar as I did in the enclosing view. "saveRect" in my example

Comment: Changing `frame` has no effect. What do you want me to try instead?

Comment: I created a small test app with a SearchDisplayController, UISearchBar and a UISegmentedControl under the search bar. I set a constraint for Center X Alignment on the Segmented Control. It stays cedntered and small for the iPad. @jonathanpeppers can you post a screen shot of your IB? I think I'm not totally understanding what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Well, this is the first time you've mentioned using a constraint. This app also needs to support iOS 5 and constraints are iOS 6 only -- I still need it to center on iOS 5.